# PHP page with MySQL not showing/working

Tags: php, mysql

The following code is not working as the page displays nothing, and I am not exactly sure why. It gets a few things from the URL and then the final Album name from the database. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$cart1 = rawurldecode($_GET["path"]);
list( , , , , , $cart2) = explode ("\\", $cart1);
$cart3 = $cart2;
list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);

$con = mysql_connect("SERVER","USER","PASS");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("cartmatch", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartmatch WHERE CARTNO='$cart4'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="albumgo.php" method="POST"><input name="ID" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["ID"];
echo ' ><input name="enabled" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["enabled"];
echo ' ><input name="artist" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["artist"];
echo ' ><input name="title" type="hidden" value="';
echo $_GET["title"];
echo '" >Name:<br/><input name="album" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="';
echo $row['ALBUM'];
echo '" ><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Save"></form>';
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: add error_reporting(1); just under the <?php

Comment: I just did, but nothing.

Comment: @user790068 Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); echo "testing output";` at the top instead

Comment: Then it means that there is no mysql row with variable value of $cart4

Comment: @DaveRandom I changed it, but nothing.

Comment: @fliespl what's strange is that if I were to replace $cart4 with the value it's placing there, it does work.

Comment: Not even seeing anything from the `echo "testing output";`?

Comment: try var_dump($cart1, $cart2, $cart3, $cart4); you are making so many explodes that you are probably lost with values

Comment: Can you add a typical url to the question, please?

Comment: @AndrewLeach album.php?enabled=True&artist=Love+Song&title=Welcome+Back&ID=1038&path=%5C%5CBuffalo%5Cmusic%5COn+Demand%5CM833%2BDawn+To+Dusk%2BAll+Sons+%26+Daughters%2B04.0%2B04.0%2BM.wav

Comment: @user790068 Try replacing the top 4 lines with `$pathParts = explode ("\\", $_GET['path']); $fileParts = explode(' ', array_pop($pathParts)); $cart4 = $fileParts[0];` (slightly altered from before)

Comment: I fixed it... `list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);` should have been `list($cart4) = explode ("+", $cart3);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);
```

Should have been

```
list($cart4) = explode ("+", $cart3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following code to see if there is an error in your script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Probably there is a database connection error or something preventing PHP from displaying the rest of the content.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are adding this code at the beginning of your PHP script and you continue getting a blank page once loaded?

Comment: Try adding echo mysql_num_rows($result); right after your SELECT query.